# Как получить контент со страницы через php?

Tags: php, https

Как получить контент со страницы через php?

Answer (score 3):

[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: Чем Вас не устроили примеры по ссылке ?

Comment: А Вы хотите с картинками, флэшками и анимациями?

Comment: Еще варианты через Curl,sockets,file

Comment: можете с file показать

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file.php